# Set Alarm To Alert 5 Minutes Before a certian Time

Tags: date, calendar, android-alarms

I'm trying to get Alarm Manager to alert the user 5 minutes before an event happens. How do I go about doing this?

For example, the time of the event is 10:00:00 and I need set the alarm 5 minutes earlier at 9:55:00. I wasn't able to find examples of this in my search.

Is there a date or calendar function that can set an earlier time based on a date?

Below is  the incomplete pseudo code

```
                            int index = eventTime.indexOf(':');
                String Hour =eventTime.substring(0, index);
                String Min = eventTime.substring(index + 1, index + 3);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                int em = Integer.parseInt(eventMonth);
                int ed = Integer.parseInt(eventDay);
                int ey = Integer.parseInt(eventYear);
                int h = Integer.parseInt(Hour);
                int m = Integer.parseInt(Min);

                        int alertTime=5;
                        m=m+alertTime;

                            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, em);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, ey);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ed);
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);

                            AlarmManager mgr = new AlarmManager();

                             mgr.addAlarm(cal.getTime(), new AlarmListener() {
            // public void handleAlarm(AlarmEntry entry)
            Log.v("calander", cal.toString());
            // }
            // });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo code is on the right track. Though for the `AlarmManager` you wanna do something like this:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
//pi is a PendingIntent since you want it to run some code at the point it goes off
//Look up PendingIntent on the Android docs to understand what it does if you dont already know
```

For your date thing using `Calendar`, you are doing it right. Though it would be cleaner using `set()` in this way:

```
set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute)
```

In your case, it could look like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(ey, em, ed, h, m-5);
```

As for whether something exists to make the Calendar based on date, it depends on how you want to do it. For you, I don't really think there is anything else you really can do besides supply the dates and just subtract depending on whether its minutes, hours, etc. Hopefully what I did makes sense and can actually work with what you are trying to do.