# HOW to subtract 5 minutes from AlarmManager time?

Tags: android, time, calendar, alarmmanager, timepicker

I'm trying to set an Alarm with AlarmManager. It works fine if I don't subtract any time from it but when I do it doesn't work. I want to set it 5 minutes before a specified time.

```
    long minute = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES / 15;

    alarmTime = alarmTime - (minute*5);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

This doesn't work. It just doesn't go off.

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646359/1275777?

Comment: Is `alarmTime` a `long` too?

Comment: To Norman, yes I did and tried it that way too, it was useless, it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you debug and let us see what's the values for `alarmTime` and `minute` when it fails?

Comment: @m0skit0 The only way I know how to debug is with toast and the text was too fast but it showed a long number beginning with 1 for alarmTime and minute was 60000

Comment: Do Log.D(tag, msg); and print alarmTime.toSring(); paste your logcat.

Comment: The time set by the alarm when 5 is subtracted must be right because when I show the time using the calendar add way it is the alarm time minus 5, like 2:40 would be 2:35. But it doesn't go off...

Comment: @NomanArain I did that now. The value was 1384804500474.

Comment: Can you try:
am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + TWENTY_SECONDS, pIntent);
Instead of setRepeating. Also look here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Comment: @NomanArain but that doesn't include alarmTime, also oes that go off every 7 days too?

Comment: [Learn to use the debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551818/how-to-debug-android-application-line-by-line-using-eclipse), it's easy and life-saving.